# Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, integer

I'm trying to print my current location and I have this error:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'
```

My code:

```dart
class AssiMethod {
  static Future<String> searchCooredinationAdress(Position position) async {
    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    String Adressplace = "";
    String url =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?${position.latitude},${position.altitude}=$mapKey";
    var responce = await RequestAssist.getReqeust(url);
    if (responce != "echech") {
      Adressplace = responce["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
    }

    return Adressplace;
  }
}


class RequestAssist {
  static Future<dynamic> getReqeust(String url) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    try {
      if (response == 200) {
        String jSondata = response.body;
        var decoData = jsonDecode(jSondata);
        return decoData;
      } else {
        return "echec de repense";
      }
    } catch (exp) {
      return "echec";
    }
  }
}
String adresse = await AssiMethod.searchCooredinationAdress(position);
    print("adresse " + adresse);
```

Comment: Which line the error pointed to?

Comment: I think you wanted to check response.statusCode == 200. The types are not related.
You should check the clean code book for better quality of code.

Comment: searchCooredinationAdress  i think